# Print large land area using QGIS 2.6.1 Brighton

Tags: qgis, printing, print-composer

I have a rectangular area of approximately 10km x 20km and I wish to print this to A0.
(I will select a scaled portion of this area - most of it - that matches the A0 page size)

I have a few layers in QGIS with OpenCycleMap in the background (lowest layer).

I wish to print a good quality print.

What is the best way to get my features out of QGIS and into a file format that will preserve detail for A0 print while showing crisp definition ?

Comment: if your osm tiles are coming from the web they will only be 256 dpi http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Resolution_and_Scale. You need to render from vector files to get 600+ dpi

Comment: see osm vector (work in progress) for the best quality output http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Resolution_and_Scale